# Is the series $\sum_k\left| \frac{1}{\ln{(k+1)}}\right|^p$ divergent for $p > 1$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, proof-verification, divergent-series

### Let $p > 1$. Is the series $$\sum_k\left| \frac{1}{\ln{(k+1)}}\right|^p$$ divergent?

---

This is in the context of finding a sequence that goes to zero but is not an element of $l^p$ space.
I saw in another post that this can be proved to be divergent by the limit comparison test using $x_k = \frac{1}{k}$ as the testing sequence. I'm attempting to show this below, assuming that $1 + k > e$.

Let $y_k = \left| \frac{1}{\ln{(k+1)}}\right|^p$, and $x_k = \frac{1}{k}$, then

\begin{align} 
\lim_{k\to \infty}\left|\frac{y_k}{x_k}\right| &= \lim \frac{k}{\left[\ln(k+1)\right]^p} \\ \\
&\overset{l'h}{=} \frac{1}{p}\lim \frac{k+1}{\left[\ln(k+1)\right]^{p-1}} \\ \\
&\overset{l'h}{=} \frac{1}{p(p-1)}\lim \frac{k+1}{\left[\ln(k+1)\right]^{p-2}} \\ \\
&\, \, \, \vdots \\ \\
&\overset{l'h}{=} \frac{1}{p(p-1)\cdots(p-n)}\lim \frac{k+1}{\left[\ln(k+1)\right]^{p-n}}
\end{align}

Since $p > 1$ is fixed, there must exist an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $p - n \leq 0$. For that value of $n$ let $p - n = -a$. Then

\begin{align}
\frac{1}{p\cdots(p-n)}\lim \frac{k+1}{\left[\ln(k+1)\right]^{p-n}}
&= \frac{1}{p\cdots(p-n)}\lim \frac{k+1}{\left[\ln(k+1)\right]^{-a}} \\ \\
&=\frac{1}{p\cdots(p-n)}\lim (k+1){\left[\ln(k+1)\right]^{a}} \\ \\
&\longrightarrow \infty \quad \text{ as } \quad k \longrightarrow \infty
\end{align}

Therefore, by my recollection of the limit comparison test, this proves that the sequence term in the numerator $y_k$ must be larger than the denominator term $x_k$ at some value of $k$, and then forever more. Basically, the top is bigger than the bottom and the bottom has a divergent series, so the top must represent the terms of a divergent series.

---

Is this proof sufficient? And/or does anybody have simpler proof lying around? Also, I tried the integral test on this but is seemed difficult, so is it possible that way?

Comment: It comes down to $\ln x=o(n^a)$ for any $a>0$.  Which comes down to $x=o(e^{ax})$ for any $a>0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple proof using [the Cauchy Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).

Observe
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=2}\frac{1}{|\ln k|^p}
\end{align}
is convergent if and only if 
\begin{align}
\sum_{\ell=1}2^\ell \frac{1}{|\ln 2^\ell|^p}
\end{align}
is convergent. 
However, for the latter sum, we see that
\begin{align}
\sum_{\ell=1} \frac{2^\ell}{\ell^p |\ln 2|^p} = \frac{1}{|\ln 2|^p}\sum_{\ell=1} \frac{2^\ell}{\ell^p}
\end{align}
which is clearly divergent for any $p>1$ since $2^\ell/\ell^p \rightarrow \infty$ as $\ell\rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Nice, thank you. Just curious, was my proof valid?